# Queue isEmpty Troubleshooting

Tags: java, queue

When compliling the program I have no problem but when I try to run the program I get a NullPointerException. I have no clue why I have this and how to get rid of this.

Error is on this line:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
```

Code:

```
public class TheChair {
    private Customer[] chairQueue = null;

    public void TheChair(){
        chairQueue = new Customer[1];
    }

    public void enchairQueue( Customer newItem){
        if(chairQueue[0] == null){
            chairQueue[0] = newItem;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The chair is full.");
        }
    }

    public void dechairQueue(){
        System.out.println(chairQueue[0].getName() + " has left");
        chairQueue[0] = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(chairQueue[0] == null){
            System.out.println("The Barber's chair is empty");
            System.out.println();
            return true;
        } else{
                System.out.println("The Barber's chair is filled by: ");
                System.out.println(chairQueue[0].getName());
                return false;
        }
    }
```

I'm not really sure how I should troubleshoot this and this is just a small part of code of the program.

Comment: This is just the class definition.  Could you also include the unit test or application code that you are running?

Comment: It is too much code to post here so I will set a link to it for viewing. http://www.mediafire.com/?x2oaxmz1fb866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to make a constructor with these lines?

```
public void TheChair(){
    chairQueue = new Customer[1];
}
```

If yes, then this is wrong code for your purpose since the constructor doesn't have a return type and should be coded as:

```
public TheChair(){
    chairQueue = new Customer(1);
}
```

Also, notice that **new Customer[1]** in your "constructor" doesn't make a Customer object, instead, it tries to indexing an array named Customer.

If no, it's the same since the instance variable chairQueue is not instantiated anyway.

Then, as you don't have a proper constructor, your instance variable chairQueue is not initialized at all. When you call isEmpty() with any instance of TheChair class, chairQueue itself is null. As a consequence, in the function when the statement **chairQueue[0]** is evaluated, it is trying to indexing a null object(pointer), which throws NullPointerException.